# setting up testing environment with Vagrant Virtual Machine and Nginx

Tags: linux, ssl, nginx, vagrant, webserver

I'm trying to set up a local web testing environment with Vagrant on a centos/6 virtual machine

In the vagrant configuration I set: `config.vm.network    "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080`

Inside of the vagrant box if I type: `hostname -I` it gives me a result of 
10.0.2.15

```
In the vagrant box, nginx is already set and I do have a SSL certification and HTTPS connection set up:
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name 127.0.0.1:8000;
    ...(other configurations including ssl_certificate, 
    ssl_certificate_key,protocols and cipher)
    ...(other values that I think its not relevant)
    location / {
            if ($http_host != 127.0.0.1:8000) {
                return 444;
            }
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

And then I have:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name ~^;
    return 302 https://127.0.0.1:8000$request_uri;
}
```

In my vagrant box, if I use `curl` to get the content at 127.0.0.1:8000: `curl 127.0.0.1:8000`, I'm able to successfully get the expected content

From my host operating system, when I'm using chrome to request access to 127.0.0.1, it simply says `The connection was reset.` and the error exception code is `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

My best guess is this has to deal with my SSL configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, I run vagrant and use Virtualbox as my hypervisor. You will need to check what the vagrant box is doing for NAT. On mine, out of the box it is 192.169.33.10 and that will get to my dev box. Assumes port forwarding is set right and no firewall.

What does 192.168.33.10:8080 do?

Comment: thanks for your respond, I did not set up my 'config.vm.network :private_network' to any IP address yet, if I send a HTTP request to 192.168.33.10:8080 it kept requesting for a while and give me a timeout, let me try setup the private network first.

Comment: Ok, once I set up and restarted my vagrant, I tried to connect to 192.169.33.10:8080, it says connection refused, 192.168.33.10 refused to connect.

Comment: Here are the important parts of my vagrant        file:config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10" and config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest:8000, host:8000

Comment: The VM image I use. Checkout the vagrant file [link](https://github.com/ChrisTheDBA/scotch-box)

Comment: ok great, so do I need to configure my nginx listen to 192.169.33.10 ? I just recently known that 127.0.0.1 is a loop back address pointing to the localhost itself and its suggested not to use this address.

Comment: No, you should be able to set the NGINX to accept on all addresses with and asterisk. Other than that make sure you environment doesn't have the firewall rejecting the requests.

Comment: thanks, both 0.0.0.0:8000 and 127.0.0.1:8000 are giving me a connection reset error, and I didn't set my Vagrant file'f private network, but I think my guest machine is giving me response.